# Reference check

Tags: references, background-check

I was restaurant manager 2 years back outside US. Now I found new job and they are asking 3 years worth of reference contact details. It's hard for me to get contact details. What should I tell them?

Comment: Tell them the truth

Comment: WHERE outside the US?  In Europe it should be fairly easy to get references on the phone.  In the Philippines it might be a bit trickier.  Can you use the search engine map sites to show the current employer where the restaurant is?

Answer (score 3):

> What should I tell them?

That depends on how long it will take you to come up with the necessary references.

If it's hard, but you can get it done with a handful of phone calls or emails, then don't tell them anything, just do it.

If it's hard, and thus will take a few days to achieve, tell them "No problem. But because my job was outside of the US it will likely take me a few days. Will that be ok?"

If it's hard, and thus you don't think you can get the references at all that they would prefer, say something like "I'm not sure I can get you references as far back as you would like, because the jobs weren't in the US. Can I just give you what I have?"

Comment: Perhaps you could give them the name and location of the restaurant, and also follow the above process regarding getting actual specific contact details for an individual who can specifically give you a reference?